# How to update map objects in array?

Tags: javascript

I have array of map objects, want to update two properties  of each object.

1. accountId
2. handlerId

**Updated:**

Here is how array of map objects looks:

[image: Image of console data]

```
data: {
  COMP_011234567      NYWC-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU: {
    accountId: "1234567      "
    accountKey: "COMP_011234567      "
    accountName: "Test123 "
    adjusterClaimType: "WC"
    adjusterKey: "COMP_01WC-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU"
    assignmentRulesKey: "COMP_011234567      NYWC"
    companyAdjusterId: 1111111
    companyId: "COMP_01"
    exception: false
    handlerId: "-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU"
    key: "COMP_011234567      NYWC-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU"
    lineOfBusiness: "WC"
    name: "WC Med Only Direct Without skills - All states"
    selectedState: "NY"
    tpa: "no"
    tpaCompany: ""
    }
}

I need to trim() accountId and handlerId.


// Already tried this apporach: 

  data.forEach(i => {
    i.accountId = i.accountId.trim();
    i.handlerId = i.handlerId.trim();
  })
```

Comment: The original object is quite unclear. I mean, the structure is unclear. Can you please share a better log of it?

Comment: Any errors in console when you try the trim shown? Should work fine if those properties are direct children of `i`. Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: Your object doesnt actually look like an array in that screenshot. It looks like a plain object

Comment: right, my bad in description of question.

Comment: You're trying to use `Array` functions on an object....not going to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it immutably with [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries).

1. Iterate over your inner objects with `Object.entries`.
2. Iterate over this list of key/values pairs with `reduce`:

   1. For each entry, map the object to a shallow copy with the spread operator.
   2. Then trim `accountId` and `handlerId` and assign them to the right properties.
   3. Finally, assign the new object to the right key in the accumulator.

```js
const data = {
  'COMP_011234567      NYWC-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU': {
    accountId: "1234567      ",
    accountKey: "COMP_011234567      ",
    accountName: "Test123 ",
    adjusterClaimType: "WC",
    adjusterKey: "COMP_01WC-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU",
    assignmentRulesKey: "COMP_011234567      NYWC",
    companyAdjusterId: 1111111,
    companyId: "COMP_01",
    exception: false,
    handlerId: "-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU",
    key: "COMP_011234567      NYWC-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU",
    lineOfBusiness: "WC",
    name: "WC Med Only Direct Without skills - All states",
    selectedState: "NY",
    tpa: "no",
    tpaCompany: ""
  }
};


const result = Object.entries(data).reduce((acc, [key, x]) => {
  acc[key] = { ...x, accountId: x.accountId.trim(), handlerId: x.handlerId.trim() };
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to trim property from an object, you can directly use `trim()` function on the property.

```js
var data = {
  accountId: "1234567      ",
  handlerId: "-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU    ",
}

data.accountId = data.accountId.trim();
data.handlerId = data.handlerId.trim();
console.log(data)
```

If you want to trim properties from the all the objects in an array, you can iterate over the array using `forEach()` and then use `trim()` on the property.

```js
var dataArr = [
  {
    accountId: "1234567      ",
    handlerId: "-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU      ",
  },
  {
    accountId: "1234567      ",
    handlerId: "-LLUVULylrqhqq5QkMTU      ",
  }
];

dataArr.forEach(d => {
  d.accountId = d.accountId.trim();
  d.handlerId = d.handlerId.trim();
});

console.log(dataArr);
```